# Ubuntu 16.04: Menu Bar (Sublime Text, Terminal, etc) missing

Tags: permissions, sudo, gnome-terminal, menu-bar

It only appears when run with sudo.

[image: Running Sublime-Text 3 with root permissions]

[image: Running gnome-terminal with root permissions]

Comment: Can you check if it shows in the title bar on the top menu bar when you hover your pointer over these? I can only see the menu when I hover over the window's title bar.

Comment: @adonis Before I run `unity` as suggested I tried to look on the title bar and the menu bar was still missing.

Comment: The default location of the menu in 16.04 is on the very top. Holding Alt or hovering the mouse reveals it. I just thought to mention it because I don't think it's obvious.

Comment: I believe you're facing this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bamf/+bug/1532226

Comment: @adonis Yeah, I tried that. Even holding alt didn't work for me. The only way that I found was running as root and this shows a menu bar in a different position as you can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a terminal and type `unity` and hit <kbd>return</kbd>, after you have your desktop back close the terminal and reopen it normally. Actually i have the same problem on my second computer but i do this direct after boot up and have then menu bars everywhere. As far i know this is a known bug and a fix is in the making, just couldn't find the link anymore.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, if my post helped you you can accept it as an answer by clicking the checkmark beside it.

Comment: restaring the unity shell and restarting the affected applications in that order works for me

Answer (score 0):

Press `CTRL+ALT+T` and type in `unity` - Once you've pressed `Enter` on your keyboard, it should prompt you to login. Login, and hopefully you will see your Unity desktop! In my opinion, the Unity desktop environment, including the launcher, is very organized and clean. I use the Gnome Tweak Tool and I use the Oxygen theme (GTK) to provide extra cleanse to my OS. I have Ubuntu 14.04 dual booting with Windows 7 Professional, and since the day I got Ubuntu, I haven't used Windows. Funny. Anyway, to get back on topic, press `CTRL + ALT + T` once more and type in `sudo -s` - This will prompt you for your password, and allow you to get root permissions. Once you're in the root, type in `unity` again and send that command into the terminal by pressing `return` or `enter`. Then, login once more, and open the Terminal, AGAIN. Simply close it, and you should be good. This worked for me on my Chromebook Pixel, and hopefully it will work for you. By the way, I didn't use ChromeOS on the Chromebook Pixel - I got Ubuntu and then erased ChromeOS off of it. Chromebook Pixel computers are basically the best laptops on the market, except for the OS. But once you've  got a certain file called "crouton" it will allow you to enter a certain command into the terminal, returning in Ubuntu! You can even specify a desktop environment, but I would stick to Unity, and then manually run `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-full` for the clean Oxygen theme and KDE-simple cursor/window pack.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that easiest way to fix the problem is to reinstall ubuntu desktop.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

I hope this would work for you also.